# Start server: /bin/sh: 1: /etc/init.d/mysql: not found

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have tried MySQL workbench on linux mint 14, and got this

> Start server: /bin/sh: 1: /etc/init.d/mysql: not found

error when trying to start local server on it. Please help how to resolve this issue. I haven't installed anything MySQL related but this.

Answer (score 1):

> I haven't installed anything MySQL related but this.

This right here is the problem. If you want to start a local MySQL server, you of course need to ahve the MySQL server installed.

The error message clearly states this: MySQL workbench is trying to call the init-script of the MySQL daemon, but it's not there.

Comment: Could you please guide me to where I can do that. I have downloads tarball for dev.mysql.com for MySQL Community Server 5.6.16, but I don't know what to do with that tar.

Comment: @user3084657 mint linux features a package manager (mintInstall). You should use it to install software (if its available there, but I'm certain mysql is). no need to download and compile manually.